# Conjecture of Metric Dimension of a Maximal planar graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a finite, simple, and connected graph. We say a vertex $u$ in $G$ *resolves* two other vertices $v$ and $w$ in $G$ if the distance from $u$ to v is not equal to the distance from $u$ to $w$. A subset of vertices of $G$ is a *resolving set* of $G$ if there exists a vertex in the set that resolves each pair of vertices in $G$. The *metric dimension* of $G$ is the smallest cardinality of a resolving set. Let us denote this by $\Lambda(G)$.

A graph is said to be *planar* if there exists a drawing of it on the plane such that no two edges intersect except at the vertices. Planar graphs have faces, which are contiguous regions enclosed by edges. We call a planar graph *maximal planar* if all the faces of the graph are enclosed by three edges.

**Conjecture:** For maximal planar graphs with $n$ vertices we have $\Lambda(G) \approx \lfloor2n/5\rfloor$

Any help to prove/disprove the conjecture would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing anything yet that could indicate otherwise, It's quite possible that this is a research level question to which one could dedicate much of a paper. 

Do you have any reason to believe this is solveable under reasonable time and space constraints? 

If you have more thoughts on this, and why you conjecture the bound you do, it may even be more appropriate for Math Overflow, or a research project.

Comment: There exist lots of infinite families of maximal planar graphs with metric dimension much lower than that. For example the edge graphs of all geodesic polyhedra obtained by regularly subdividing icosahedra have metric dimension at most $12$, their actual metric dimension might be as low as $4$.

Comment: The only info I can find online is a preprint which also has this conjecture: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04066